# Multipart Retrofit 1.9 -> 2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I used to send **POST** request with **Retrofit 1.9**:

```
TypedFile typedFile =  picture != null ? new TypedFile("image/*", tempFile) : null;

@Multipart
@POST("/goals")
Observable<Goal> postGoal(
        @Part("name") String name,
        @Part("picture") TypedFile picture
        );
```

I moved to **retrofit 2.0.2** but I can't make it working the same. According to https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1140 I used:

```
RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), name);
RequestBody picture = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), tempFile);


    @Multipart
    @POST("goals")
    Observable<Goal> postGoal(
            @Part("name") RequestBody name,
            @Part("picture\"; filename=\"temp.png\" ") RequestBody picture
    );
```

But it seems request is going without the file (photo). What is wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To upload image using retrofit 2.0, you can use MultipartBody.Part as parameter of your image. Hope this solution fix your problem.

**Your API declaration**

```
@Multipart
@POST("/goals")
Observable<Goal> postGoal(@Part("name") String name, @Part MultipartBody.Part imageFile);
```

**Your api call**

```
RequestBody imageName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), name);

//prepare image file
File file = new File(imagePath);
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
MultipartBody.Part imageFileBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestBody);

YourAPI service = retrofit.create(YourAPI.class);
Call<Goal> call = service.postGoal(imageName, imageFileBody);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Goal>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Goal> call, Response<Goal> response) {
        //handle success
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Goal> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I found as well. I hoped though there will be clearer solution ;) Thx!